# Strategy for business object editor

Tags: vb.net

Question from a newbie: I have a dictionary "Semester" of business objects "Sections" I'd like to pass this by reference into an editor instantiated from a SemesterEditor class, edit it there.

```
Class SemesterEditor
Sub New(ByRef semester As Semester)
End Sub
(code)
End Class
```

Inside the SemesterEditor however, a Section should have more editing-relevant attributes than it normally does (for example, its position on a display etc. ) I know such  richer sections could be created by instantiating from a class say "SectionView" which is inherited from the "Section" class

Ideally what I'd like to do is pass Semester by reference into SemesterEditor, via some kind of casting (?) convert the Sections in Semester to SectionView objects, edit them, and keep the binding with the original Sections so changes are recorded in Semester. Is something like that possible?

Or do I really have to, inside SemesterEditor, run a parallel dictionary of SectionViews, each created from Sections, make changes to to those, convert back to Secctions and write back to semester, the parameter dictionary of Sections?

Or is there some other way that I don't have to create a whole new parallel structure?

Apologies for the naive question! I hope I have the lingo right.

Comment: `ByRef semester As Semester` doesn't look like a dictionary. More like `ByRef dict As Dictionary(Of Integer, Semester)` or whatever type you want to use as key.

Comment: Right, should have mentioned that Semester inherits from dictionary, so it is one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast an instance of a base class to the type of a derived class, so creating a "`SectionView`" class which inherits from `Section` won't work in this particular case.

I would recommend a declaring `SectionView` as it's own independent class which sort of wraps around an instance of `Section`. Something like this for example:

```
Public Class SectionView()
    Public Sub New(S as Section)
        Section = S
    End Sub

    Public Property Section As Section

    'Other editing-specific properties
End Class
```

This way you can reference the existing instances of `Section` via the `Section` property.